# Obtain SQL Server Reporting Services URLs programmatically in C#

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I need to obtain the SQL Server Reporting Services report manager and report Web Service URLs programmatically to configure my reports on the fly. What is the best way of doing that?  For example the default value is http://server/reports, but it is not always the case. Let's assume I have SQL host name and instance for that (if needed).
I also could see the SSRS web service URL when connecting to Reporting Services via the Management Studio. So theoretically it could be obtained via a connection string to the Reporting Services.

Comment: You need to specify platform such as winform, asp.net, mvc, etc. Also better is describing what you have tried so far.

Comment: I'm going to use a class library, no specific platform. I tried the way with WMI (ListReservedURLs), but it is not preferable way to me.